# Switch to manually confirmed incoming shipments in OpenERP 6.0.3

Tags: openerp

When I convert a purchase request for quotation to a purchase order in the same moment an incoming shipment is generated, which is fine. But the incoming shipment is already in state "Done".

I could not find out how to change this. The incoming shipment should be handled manually.

This is OpenERP 6.0.3. Can you help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean confirmed or done? You could try experimenting with the autopicking property of the product you're purchasing, but I don't think that will affect what you're doing.

Comment: They are all in "Done" state from the beginning. I updated the question, it was ambigous, sorry. I will check if I find an autopicking property on the products.

Comment: How can I modify the autopicking property of the product? I was not able to find it.

Comment: There's a module called `stock_no_autopicking` that lets you turn it off, @mit.